# Is it possible to read data from a file and store to a PRACTICE variable created using VAR.NEWGLOBAL

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I found an example, with

```
READ #1 "filename.hex" &data
```

were &data is a PRACTICE macro. I need to parse this data. As it is stored in a macro, I am not able to. Is it possible to store it in a PRACTICE variable? If so what would the command look like?

Comment: Could you post an example of the line (and/or the file)  you are trying to parse?

Answer (score 0):

You can not read data from a file and store it to a PRACTICE variable directly. However you can read the data to a PRACTICE macro and assign the content of the macro to a PRACTICE variable:

```
PRIVATE &data                     // declare macro
VAR.NEWGLOBAL char[64] \mydata    // declare variable
READ #1 "filename.hex" &data      // read data from file to macro
Var.Set \mydata="&data"           // assign content from macro to variable
```

Note: Macros do only work in PRACTICE script files (*.cmm-files). They do not work in the TRACE32 command line.

Anyhow **if you need to parse the data** from the file, I would suggest to read-in the complete line from the file to a macro with format option `%LINE` and then extract the required content from the macro with the STRing-PRACTICE functions like `STRing.SPLIT()` or `STRing.MID()` or `STRing.SCANAndExtract()`.

E.g. Get the value from the third column of a CSV file:

```
PRIVATE &data &value                // declare macros
VAR.NEWGLOBAL char[64] \mydata      // declare variable
READ #1 "filename.csv" %LINE &data  // read one line from file to macro
&value=STRing.TRIM(STRing.SPLIT("&data",",",2))   // get 3rd comma separated value
Var.Set \mydata="&value"            // assign content from macro to variable
```

Comment: Thanks for enlightening about the STRing-PRACTICE functions.